# How to find the most significant bit of a signed integer in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I need to find the most significant bit of signed int N and save it in signBitN. I want to do this using bitwise only operations.
Also, how would I make signBitN extend so that all its bits are equal to its significant bit.
i.e. if it's significant bit was zero, how would I extend that to be 00000...00?
The closest I've gotten is signBitN=1&(N>>(sizeof(int)-1));

Comment: What is N? Do you want to find the sign bit of a particular type, like `int` or `int16_t`?

Comment: shift by `(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1)`

Comment: There's no particular benefit of doing this with bitwise operators over the obvious `(N < 0)` or `(N < 0) ? -1 : 0`.  If there are clever bitwise approaches, let your compiler's optimizer insert them for you.  [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yoesh3).

Comment: N is a signed int

Comment: Are you asking what is the most significant bit position, or do you want to find the first `1`?

Comment: I want the bit at the most significant position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portable expression:

```
1 & (x >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1))
```

Latest C standards put 3 standards on representation of ints.

- sign and magnitude
- one complement
- two complement
  See section `6.2.6.2  Integer types` of C11 standard.

Only the third option is relevant in practice for modern machines.
As specified in `6.2.6.1`:

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
> consist of n x CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that type,
> in bytes.

Therefore `int` will consist of `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` bits, likely 32.
Thus the highest bit of `int` can be read by shifting right by `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1` bits and reading the last bit with bitwise `&` operator.

Note that the exact value of the `int` after the shift is implementation defined as stated in `6.5.7.5`.

On sane machines it would be:

```
int y = x < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

The portable way would be casting between `int` and an array of `unsigned char` and setting all bytes to `-1`.
See `6.3.1.3.2`:

> if the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by
> repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than  the  maximum
> value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type until the value
> is in the range of the new type.

And `6.2.6.1.2`

> Values  stored  in  unsigned  bit-fields  and  objects  of  type
> unsigned  char shall  be represented using a pure binary notation.

You can use `memset()` for that.

```
int x;
memset(&x, (x < 0 ? -1 : 0), sizeof x);
```

Comment: If `x` is negative then `x >>` has an implementation-defined result. Some implementations may fill with zero bits , for example.

Comment: @M.M, yes it's implementation defined. But the question was about value of the highest bit *before* shifting

Comment: The entirety of the result is implementation-defined  ; the standard doesn't guarantee that your first suggestion will give the right answer .  So perhaps "portable" is not a good description of that code.

Comment: @M.M Yes. The result of the operation is implementation defined because the bit representation of 'int' is implementation defined. Maybe first the concept of the highest bit should be defined.

Comment: @tstanisl so why to use it if t is not portable?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to check the MSB bit of the integer (for example 31st bit of the 32 bit integer) ten IMO this is portable.

```
#define MSB(i)   ((i) & (((~0U) >> 1) ^ (~0U)))
#define issetMSB(i) (!!MSB(i))

int main(void)
{
    printf("%x\n", MSB(-1));
    printf("%x\n", issetMSB(-1));
}
```

Comment: ...if "cast to unsigned" is one of the allowed operations  (not clear from the OP)

Comment: @M.M is cast in not allowed then it is not possible in the portable C.

Comment: @M.M cast in not needed